# C#: Is a private inner interface possible?

Tags: c#, generics, visibility, covariance, nested-class

I have a generic class `X<T>`; This class has a covariant part that I want to be able to access covariantly. So I factor it out into an interface `IX<out T>`. However, I want this interface to be visible only to the class itself, because it contains also methods that are ment to be `private`.

I.e., inside the class itself, I can upcast to `IX<T>` and use it covariantly. E.g.:

```
class X<T> : IX<T> {

    private interface IX<out T>{ // the private covariant interface
         void foo();
    }

    // It grants access to the private method `foo`
    private T foo(){...}
    public T IX.foo(){ return foo(); }

    private static void someMethod(IX<T> x) {
        // Here I can use `x` covariantly
    }
}
```

Is this possible? I have never heard of `private` nested interfaces before, since a private interface usually makes no sence at all. However, with generics such an interface becomes necessary for implementing "private-only covariance".

When I try to compile this, I receive the following error:

```
foo.cs(1,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IX' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
foo.cs(9,14): error CS0305: Using the generic type `X<T>.IX<S>' requires `1' type argument(s)
```

Which is basically clear, an inner type of a generic type needs a type parameter for the outer type. Is there a way to get this code to compile correctly?

Comment: why not private class, but interface ?

Comment: @Tigran: Because a class cannot be declared covariant and I may want to inherit from another class.

Comment: Can't you just declare your interface internal, so that it will be only visible inside your assembly?

Comment: @Sahuagin: Sorry, forgot to add my compiler's output :)

Comment: @Brizio: This would be okay as well, but would not grant the very tight access restriction I am aiming at.

Comment: @Sahuagin actually, seeing as it seems to change between compilers; no, I don't think it is :p

Answer (score 9):

Edit: it looks like this compiles on the [Roslyn / C# 6 tech preview](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=52793), but does not compile on the MS C# 5 compiler or the mono compiler.

---

Yes, like this - but note that actually the inner `T` is unnecessary in many ways, and if you retain it - it would be useful to name it `TInner` or something to avoid confusion, since the `T` in `X<T>` is *technically* a different thing than `X<>.IX<T>`, even though they will always be the same actual type in practice:

```
class X<T> : X<T>.IX<T>
{

    private interface IX<out TInner>
    { // the private covariant interface
        void foo();
    }

    // It grants access to the private method `foo`
    private T foo() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    void X<T>.IX<T>.foo() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    private static void someMethod(IX<T> x)
    {
        // Here I can use `x` covariantly
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems odd that something that's `private` to a class can be accessed externally (i.e. outside the class).

Comment: @James it *isn't* accessed externally.

Comment: So it can't be accessed from another class in the same assembly via `X<T>.IX<T>`?

Comment: @James no; it can only be used by `X<T>` and other types declared *inside* `X<T>`.

Comment: Ah, neat didn't know that +1 :)

Comment: @James you would not be able to declare a `X<T>.IX<T>` reference anywhere else.

Comment: This causes a compiler error: Circular base class dependency involving 'X<T>' and 'X<T>.IX<TInner>'

Comment: @mikez compiles just fine here; what compiler are you using? I'm using the Roslyn preview

Comment: Just fired it up in an IDE and I get the same circular ref error, that's in VS2012

Comment: I believe I copied correctly. See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eMaQCj). It might be fixed in a newer build of Roslyn. I don't doubt that.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I tried it with the mono compiler: Same error. Was there a change in the specification to allow this or are simply all compilers except the Roslyn preview buggy?

Comment: @gexicide I genuinely don't know; it is intriguing

Comment: @gexicide some folks in the know have clarified that this would be considered a fix in Roslyn

Comment: Yes. This is a fix in Roslyn. In some cases the the old compiler was too strict in its cycle analysis. Roslyn tries to enforce just the minimally required set of rules.

Comment: It's interesting "linguistically" but I don't understand how it can be useful in real life design. When we said using a method covariantly for a parameter T, we know which type T' is it's subclass. Example like void f(SomeClass<Animal> x), we can pass a type x' which is SomeClass<Dog> because we are certain Dog is a subclass of Animal. Inside a generic class X<T>, we don't know what T will be used as parameter when X<T> is instantiated, because T could be anything. So the private method void someMethod(IX<T> x) in this question how can you find a T' which is definitely a subclass of T?

Answer (score -1):

In order for it to compile and limit the visibility of your interface just to your assembly you can mark it as internal. The thing is if it's declared as an inner type it won't be seen by your class. This code should work:

```
internal interface IX<out T> // the private covariant interface
{ 
    T foo();
}

class X<T> : IX<T> 
{
    // It grants access to the private method `foo`
    private T foo(){ return default(T); }
    T IX<T>.foo(){ return foo(); }

    private static void someMethod(IX<T> x)
    {
        // Here I can use `x` covariantly
    }
}
```

This way the interface is still private, but as it's not an inner type anymore it can be used on your class.

Comment: Are `private` interfaces at namespace level allowed? I thought only `internal` and `public` was allowed there... Yep, tried it. Got a compiler error stating exactly this.

Comment: You're right, I tested it using Linqpad, which apparently puts everything inside an inner class.