# Why can't I inherit from a private class / interface?

Tags: c#

Why is this illegal in C#?

```
class Foo: Foo.BaseFoo //Circular base class dependency compile time error
{
   private class BaseFoo {...}

   ...
}
```

I'm not arguing when this could be useful or not, but I'd like to know what are the reasons that would disallow such code to compile. A similar restriction happens with private interfaces.

**UPDATE**

Seeing that its a duplicate I'll center the question more in why this isn't valid with interfaces which seems more useful?

And, what's more, why does it seem to be legal with the Roslyn preview as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820885/c-is-a-private-inner-interface-possible)

Comment: To compile BaseFoo, Foo has to be compiled first. To compile Foo, BaseFoo has to be compiled first. To compile BaseFoo ...

Comment: @Fildor: That's not strictly true. Why does `Foo` *have* to be compiled before `BaseFoo` in the general case?

Comment: @Tomtom: No, it will give the same compiler error.

Comment: @Jon That was just a shot into the blue, but that's what I am reading out of the error message.

Comment: There are two issues here, one is the class inheriting a nested class, the other is a class inheriting a less visible class.

Comment: @Fildor There is no evidence to suggest this is true. The C# compiler is two-pass, it checks type declarations and signatures before moving on to code inside methods. This is probably more an explicit design choice more than a technical limitation. There may be hidden gotchas we can't see, and there may be technical limitations in the compiler, but it does seem arbitrary.

Comment: @Fildor: After seeing the dupe it seems the issue is as I initially suspected: there is no technical reason this can't be done, but it would introduce a lot of complexity for very very little apparent benefit.

Comment: @Lukazoid Making both classes public does not change the outcome, and the question was *why* the first is an issue, not *whether* it is an issue.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am merely stating that even if inheriting from nested classes were supported, this situation would still have an issues with inheriting from a less visible class. But you are correct, the current issue is because of the nested class.

Comment: @Jon and Lasse : I see. My statement actually just was a quick and dirty interpretation of the error message. Thank you for clarification. +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of the access modifier -that the class is private. This is a circular base class dependency. You try to define a class called `Foo` that inherits a nested class called `BaseFoo`.

Comment: Why is it a circular base class dependency? `BaseFoo` does not inherit from `Foo`.

Comment: Isn't this case like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265585/why-cant-a-class-extend-its-own-nested-class-in-c ?